# Format long equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting, amsmath

I have this equation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
   \frac{u(x,t)-u(x,t-k)}{k}=c\frac{u(x+h,t)-2u(x,t)+u(x-h,t)}{h^2}+(\frac{u(x+h,t)-u(x-h,t)}{2h})(\frac{c(x+h,t)-c(x-h,t)}{2h}) \\
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that it goes off the page. So I tried:

```
\begin{align}
  \frac{u(x,t)-u(x,t-k)}{k} \\
  =& c\frac{u(x+h,t)-2u(x,t)+u(x-h,t)}{h^2}+(\frac{u(x+h,t)-u(x-h,t)}{2h})(\frac{c(x+h,t)-c(x-h,t)}
  {2h})
\end{align}
```

That doesn't seem to work either. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `multline`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
  \frac{u(x,t)-u(x,t-k)}{k} 
  = c\frac{u(x+h,t)-2u(x,t)+u(x-h,t)}{h^2}\\
 +\left(\frac{u(x+h,t)-u(x-h,t)}{2h}\right)
 \left(\frac{c(x+h,t)-c(x-h,t)}{2h}\right) 
\end{multline}

\begin{multline}
  \frac{u(x,t)-u(x,t-k)}{k} 
  = c\frac{u(x+h,t)-2u(x,t)+u(x-h,t)}{h^2}\\
 +\Bigl(\frac{u(x+h,t)-u(x-h,t)}{2h}\Bigr)
 \Bigl(\frac{c(x+h,t)-c(x-h,t)}{2h}\Bigr) 
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't actually know that `\left` or `\Bigl` even existed. But looking at the way you've written the equations, `\Bigl` seems to be smaller than `\left`. Is that correct?

Comment: @dave Yes. Some do not like `\left` and `\right` so they prefer to add the parentheses by hand. I actually think that `\left(...\right)` looks better.

Comment: Same! Also just for knowledge, if I wanted to put equals in a new line, how could I do that? For example,
```
   x
     = 5 + 1
     = 6
 ```
So basically, something on the top line and having equals on the next line but on the left of it

Comment: @dave Then use `align`. `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 x &= 5 + 1\notag\\
 & = 6
\end{align}
\end{document}` The `&` goes before the `=` of the respective line.

Comment: The + sign in the second for me is showing below the middle of the right-hand side part. Would you possibly know why that is the case, but for you it shows below the left hand side?

Comment: @dave I do not understand this comment.